# How to disable Form Submit until a valid form is completed

Tags: jquery, html, regex, forms

Ok, I'm working on this form, and I'm trying to work out my own form validation since the jQuery form validator plug-in gives me a headache. I've pretty much been able to get all the validations I need from the input fields themselves, but right now I'm trying to figure out how to keep the form from submitting if someone is ignoring my error messages and somehow has an age of "CAT" (has letters in the numbers field).

I think I have an idea of how to do this, ***but I'm trying to figure out how to get the form to check for valid entries on each KEYUP, and see whether or not any given field hasClass("i-invalid"), which would then disable the submit button.*** I've gotten some of this to work with text input fields, but I don't know how I would do this with checkboxes or radio input fields. That 2nd one is important because it makes up the majority of my form.

***And then there are my RegExp variables that have suddenly stopped working.*** I know they're supposed to work, because I've used them already, and I guess I've added some code somewhere that's stopped them from working now. I haven't been able to test all of them, but I know that notLetter and notNumber should work, but don't for some reason.

here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pg9mL4ab/)

**html**

```
<h1>Survey</h1>

    <form id="survey" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">

        <table id="basic-info">
            <tr>
                <td><h3>Your Name:</h3>
                    <input type="text" name="BreederName" id="BreederName" size="30">
                    <span class="error"></span>
                </td>
                <td><h3>What year did you get involved?</h3>
                    <input type="number" name="YearStart" id="YearStart" maxlength="4" min="1925" max="2015">
                    <span class="error"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><h3>What is your Organization's Name?</h3>
                    <input type="text" name="KennelName" id="KennelName" size="30">
                    <span class="error"></span>
                </td>
                <td><h3>Do you have a website?</h3>
                    <input type="url" name="Website" id="Website" size="50">
                    <span class="error"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><h3>Would you like your contribution acknowledged on Contributor's page?</h3></br></br>
                    <input type="radio" name="credit" id="Credit" value="yes" width="20">Yes, I'd like my name, Organization name, and website listed on the Contributor's page. </br>
                    <input type="radio" name="credit" id="Credit" value="no" width="20">No, I'd rather contribute anonymously.
                    <span class="error"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table class="wrapper">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="3"><lable for="exercise"><h2>Select a number 1 - 10.</h2>
                    <span class="error"></span></lable></th>
            </tr>
                <td>
                    <div>
                    <input type="radio" name="exercise" value="1" width="20">1</br>
                    </div>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="exercise" value="2" width="20">2
                    <input type="radio" name="exercise" value="3" width="20">3</br>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="exercise" value="4" width="20">4</br>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="exercise" value="5" width="20">5
                    <input type="radio" name="exercise" value="6" width="20">6</br>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="exercise" value="7" width="20">7</br>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="exercise" value="8" width="20">8
                    <input type="radio" name="exercise" value="9" width="20">9</br>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="exercise" value="10" width="20">10</br>
                    <
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <span class="value">Is there anything you'd like to mention?</span></br></br></br>
                    <textarea name="exercise-comment" rows="10" cols="50">Maxium 500 chars</textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>

        <input type="submit" id="submit" class="invalid" value="Submit">
        <span class="submit error"></span>
            </form>
```

**jQuery**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

                    $("input").addClass("i-invalid"); //Automatically set all input fields to invalid

                    $("input").focusin(function(){//highlight input field on focus
                        $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
                    });
                    $("input").focusout(function(){
                        $(this).css("background-color", "white");
                    });

                    /*Run fields through their validators, if everything works, add a class of "Valid" or
                    something similar to check against when the submit button is hit*/

                    //RegExp variables
                    notLetters = /[^A-Za-z\s]/;
                    notNumber = /[^0-9]/;
                    notLimChar = /[^A-Za-z0-9\s.,?!]/;
                    notUrl = /^(?:(?:(?:https?|ftp):)?\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})).?)(?::\d{2,5})?(?:[/?#]\S*)?$/i;

                    //Submitter Info
                    bName = $("#BreederName");
                    year = $("#YearStart");
                    kName = $("#KennelName");
                    website = $("#Website");
                    credit = $("#Credit");

                    bNameVal = bName.val();
                    yearVal = year.val();
                    kNameVal = kName.val();
                    websiteVal = website.val();
                    creditVal = credit.val();

                    //Trait Variables
                    exercise = $("#exercise").val();
                    exComment = $("#exercise-comment").val();

                    bName.on("keyup focusout", function(){

                        if (notLetter.test($(this).val())){
                            $(this).removeClass("i-valid").addClass("i-invalid");
                            $(this).first(".error").text("Only letters are allowed");
                        } else if ($(this).val() == "") {
                            $(this).removeClass("i-valid").addClass("i-invalid");
                            $(this).next(".error").text("Please enter your name");
                        } else {
                            $(this).removeClass("i-invalid").addClass("i-valid");
                            $(this).next(".error").text("");
                        }

                    });

                    year.on("keyup focusout", function(){

                        if (notNumber.test($(this).val())){
                            $(this).removeClass("i-valid").addClass("i-invalid");
                            $(this).next(".error").text("Only numbers are allowed");
                        } else if ($(this).val() == "") {
                            $(this).removeClass("i-valid").addClass("i-invalid");
                            $(this).next(".error").text("Please enter a year");
                        } else {
                            $(this).removeClass("i-invalid").addClass("i-valid");
                            $(this).next(".error").text("");
                        }

                    });

                    kName.on("keyup focusout", function(){

                        if (notLetter.test($(this).val())){
                            $(this).removeClass("i-valid").addClass("i-invalid");
                            $(this).next(".error").text("Your entry has invalid characters");
                        } else if ($(this).val() == "") {
                            $(this).removeClass("i-valid").addClass("i-invalid");
                            $(this).next(".error").text("Please enter your kennel name");
                        } else {
                            $(this).removeClass("i-invalid").addClass("i-valid");
                            $(this).next(".error").text("");
                        }

                    });

                    website.on("keyup focusout", function(){

                        if (notUrl.test($(this).val())){
                            $(this).removeClass("i-valid").addClass("i-invalid");
                            $(this).next(".error").text("Please enter a valid web address.");
                        } else if ($(this).val() == "") {
                            $(this).removeClass("i-valid").addClass("i-invalid");
                            $(this).next(".error").text("Please enter your website URL.");
                        } else {
                            $(this).removeClass("i-invalid").addClass("i-valid");
                            $(this).next(".error").text("");
                        }

                    });

                    credit.on("keyup focusout", function(){

                        if ($(this).val() == "") {
                            $(this).removeClass("i-valid").addClass("i-invalid");
                            $(this).next(".error").text("Would you like credit?");
                        } else {
                            $(this).removeClass("i-invalid").addClass("i-valid");
                            $(this).next(".error").text("");
                        }

                    });

    // Constantly check form on keyup/mouseup for valid, completed form
                    $("input").on("keyup mouseup", function(){

                        if( bName.hasClass("i-invalid") || year.hasClass("i-invalid") || kName.hasClass("i-invalid") || website.hasClass("i-invalid") || credit.hasClass("i-invalid") || $("#exercise").hasClass("invalid") ) {

                            $("#submit").prop("disabled", true).removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
                            $(".submit").text("* All fields must be completed and contain valid entries before submitting.");
                        } else {
                            $("#submit").prop("disabled", false).removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
                            $(".submit").text("");
                        }

                    });

                });
```

I feel like my RegExp isn't working because of how I'm declaring my variables. I'm trying to make my variables global so I can access them in any function. I think that's what I've done, because as I've said, at least 2 were already working when something went wrong.

**Edit:** I just realized I left out my notUrl RegEx variable. I took it out while trying to de-bug.

**Edit 2:** my notNumber and notLimChar RegEx variables are working. I still can't figure out what's wrong with my notLetters variable. Also, notUrl is also not working, but that's not essential right now.

**Edit 3:** My notLetter is now working. I was trying to de-bug it and had left a `.first()` in the code where there shouldn't have been. I've also realized that I can't add classes to radio buttons, and I had been trying to select the radio buttons wrong in the first place. However now I'm stuck trying to figure out how to do that, and I'm very confused.

In one of my other webforms, I had used the following code to select radio buttons in jQuery, and it worked in that form:

```
theGender = $("#form input[name=gender]:checked").val();
```

However, the same code is now not working for me in this form. I've tried amending it to the following, which is still not working. When I try alerting the value, it keeps coming up as Undefined. Does anyone see a typo somewhere?

```
credit = $(":radio[name=credit]:checked");
```

(`.val()` isn't specified in this variable, it's called separately in the necessary function)

> I had added another edit, but realized what my issue was, so I deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

After the validation, if the validation fails and you want to stop the form submit process you can use event.preventDefault() function.
It will not submit the form and will keep the control on the same page.

I believe this is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to get the jQuery to register any change with my input forms, especially my radio buttons, and then determine if the entry is valid. I'm aware of the event.preventDefault(); but I'm trying to just keep the "submit" button disabled until all fields are correctly filled out.

Comment: So I think you're looking for an IF statement which will control the submit button, right??

Comment: I believe I have an IF statement which will work (it's at the bottom of my jQuery code, the $("input") function.) What I'm looking for is what EVENT I should use to make sure that every change to the form is registered, and checked against validation rules before the Submit button is activated. Also, I'm trying to get my RegEx variables to work again, as they have stopped working.

Comment: The simplest solution is to use "required" attribute in the INPUT field as shown in this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp).
It works without any jQuery and automatically stops the submission if any required field is skipped by the user.

Comment: the "required" attribute is not supported at all in Safari, which not only leaves a hole the size of a whole browser class, it also happens to be the browser I'm working from. Not only that, relying on simply using "required" doesn't keep people putting in invalid responses, such as putting "Cat" in an age field. The field wouldn't be empty, but it certainly wouldn't be valid either.

Answer (score 0):

See how to use `onsubmit`. What is usually done is to use something like `onsubmit="return checkfields()"` with `checkfields()` a function that check if fields are correctly filled. Because of the return the form will submit only if there is a `return true`. Your function should look like that :

```
 <script>
    function checkfields() {
// OFC you have to have id to your fields 
    var field1 = Document.getElementById("Field1").value;
    var field2 = Document.getElementById("Field2").value;

    if (field1 == "") {
    alert ("Please, fill the first field");
    return false; // THIS will tell the form NOT to submit
    else 
    if (field3 == "") {
    alert ("Please, fill the second field");
    return false; // THIS will tell the form NOT to submit
    }
    // and again and again
    // Here, if everything is correctly entered, just return true and the form will submit
    else {
    return true;
    }

    }
    </script>
```